# Tailor to something

Tags: vocabulary

Given an engineering department staff in an air carrier prepares an engineering order to customize FAA rule to Boeing 737 airplanes which are operated by the air carrier is it right to say:

> "The Engineering order is drawn up to tailor the FAA rule to Boeing 737 airplanes..."

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase it as

> The engineering order is drawn up to **comply with** the FAA rule <strike>to</strike> for Boeing 737 . . .

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comply) has

> **comply**
> to act according to an order, set of rules, or request
> *There are serious penalties for failure to comply with the regulations.*